# Write Dictionary to txt format in row - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting live data like below in dictionary format.

```
{'symbol': 'TSLA', 'minute': '2020/06/04 15:37', 'open': '863.94', 'high': '863.94', 'low': '863.94', 'close': '863.94'}
{'symbol': 'TSLA', 'minute': '2020/06/04 15:38', 'open': '864.0', 'high': '864.0', 'low': '864.0', 'close': '864.0'}
{'symbol': 'TSLA', 'minute': '2020/06/04 15:39', 'open': '864.28', 'high': '864.28', 'low': '864.28', 'close': '864.28'}
```

I would like to take dictionary format and convert to below format through pandas dataframe

```
TSLA   2020/06/04 15:37 863.94 863.94 863.94 863.94
TSLA   2020/06/04 15:38 864.00 864.00 864.00 864.00
TSLA   2020/06/04 15:39 864.28 864.28 864.28 864.28
```

I tried `df = pd.DataFrame(data.items())`but it is coming below output in column and index format.

```
     0                 1
0  symbol              TSLA
1  minute  2020/06/04 15:21
2    open             863.3
3    high            864.28
4     low             863.3
5   close            864.28
```

How do I update in a row into the variable like below?

```
TSLA   2020/06/04 15:37 863.94 863.94 863.94 863.94
TSLA   2020/06/04 15:38 864.00 864.00 864.00 864.00
TSLA   2020/06/04 15:39 864.28 864.28 864.28 864.28
```

Comment: why do you want to use pandas for this?

Comment: Yeah, a normal `dict` would be enough. No need for external libraries that don't come with Python by default.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

I assume your input `data` is a list of `dict`, then you can use `pd.DataFrame().from_dict(data)` to get what you want:

```
In [6]: pd.DataFrame().from_dict(data)
Out[6]:
  symbol            minute    open    high     low   close
0   TSLA  2020/06/04 15:37  863.94  863.94  863.94  863.94
1   TSLA  2020/06/04 15:38   864.0   864.0   864.0   864.0
2   TSLA  2020/06/04 15:39  864.28  864.28  864.28  864.28
```

There're also other `from_*` helpers, you can check it on the official documentation.

Comment: Thank you and I get it through this after your help. df = pd.DataFrame().from_dict([data.values()])

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't want the headers in the output (eg. symbol). You can remove that with Python's `dict.values()` function.

Then, you can convert the list to a string, separated by any separator you wish. In the example provided, it looks like you want it to be `[space][space]`.

```py
d = {'symbol': 'TSLA', 'minute': '2020/06/04 15:37', 'open': '863.94', 'high': '863.94', 'low': '863.94', 'close': '863.94'}
"  ".join(d.values())
# 'TSLA  2020/06/04 15:37  863.94  863.94  863.94  863.94'
```

If you want to see this in the terminal, you can use `print("  ".join(d.values()))`. This will write to `stdout`, where you can read it in the terminal/command prompt.

Python's `str.join` is a function that converts an iterable yielding strings into one string. For example, if you had the list `['1', '2', '3']` and called `str(' ').join` on it, it should return the strings `'1'`, `'2'`, and `'3'` separated by the string `' '`. The string can be an empty one if that is preferred (ie. `''`). The function would return `'1 2 3'`.